# delete item in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a method to remove the minimum item from an `arrayList`. I have found the minimum item correctly, however, I don't have any clue on the removing method to be honest, I believe the second half of my code is completely useless. Any help is appreciated!

```
  public Comparable remove(){
      Iterator<T> iterator=iterator();
      T min = iterator.next();
      while (iterator.hasNext())
      {  
         T next = iterator.next();
         if (min.compareTo(next) > 0) 
            min = next;
            size--;
            **Bag<T> newBag=new Bag<T>();
            for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
                newBag=(Bag<T>) data[i];
                System.out.println(newBag);**
            }
      }
    return min;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using Iterator is good idea** (it is thread safe) but you dont need to use interator here because you are not modifying the list as you iterate, also **you dont need to sort the list** to find the minmum element because that is expensive.

What you have tried is good though dont understand some of your code but try like this:

```
 public void remove(List<T> list){

    T min = Collections.min(list);

    list.remove(min)

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the minimum value from a list doing:

```
Collections.min(list);
```

And then you can remove from a list:

```
list.remove(Collections.min(list)));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can remove an object from ArrayList. What you should do is keep track of the index at which you find minimum value and then remove that element.

e.g.

```
arrayList.remove(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using built-in functions.

For `ArrayList` use `Collections.min(Name_Of_ArrayList);`

It will give you the smallest object in `ArrayList`, save that value in an `Object` variable

You can, then, remove it by using `Name_Of_ArrayList.remove(Object);`

Here's the code:

```
Object minimum= Collections.min(Name_Of_ArrayList);
Name_Of_ArrayList.remove(minimum);
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, as it is not very efficient. You can find the minimum by iterating the list once (which is `O(n)`), while sorting runs in `O(nlgn)` at best.